# Create a Pandas dataframe with columns based on comparison of other dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say I have dataframes:

```
df1:
a b
3 0
4 5
1 20

df2:
c d
2 7
5 3
0 9
```

I want to get df3 with 2 columns. Each is calculated like this (pseudocode):

```
if df1 > df2: df3 = 1
else: df3 = 0
```

All columns in df1 have to be compared to columns in df2 respectively.

So finally I want to get:

```
df3:
e f
1 0
0 1
1 1
```

I thought that df3 = df1.gt(df2) would do that, but it didn't. It gave me 4 columns. And I don't want to use lambdas, because my real data has nearly 500000 rows x 100 columns.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column names from the two data frames don't match, if you just want to compare the values, you can use `.values` to access the numpy array for comparison (this assumes the two data frames have same dimensions and you want to have an element wise comparison regardless of the dimension names/index):

```
pd.DataFrame(df1.values > df2.values, columns=list("ef")).astype(int)
```

[image]